# Unable to use Dependency Injection for NLog in .net core 3

Tags: c#, nlog, .net-core-3.1

Hello i having problem to use ILogger for Nlog.

```
private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _loggerFactory = factory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<WeatherForecastController>();
        logger.LogInformation("test");
        logger.LogTrace("trace");
        logger.LogDebug("Debug");
        logger.LogWarning("Warning");
        logger.LogError("Error");



        _logger.LogInformation("aas");
        _logger.LogTrace("trace");
        _logger.LogDebug("Debug");
        _logger.LogWarning("Warning");
        _logger.LogError("Error");
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        var logger = NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}\\NLog.config").GetLogger("aol.databaseLogger");  

        try
        { 
            logger.Debug("Starting host builder");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        } 
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddXmlFile($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}/Connections.config", optional: false);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((host, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                logging.AddNLogWeb(NLog.LogManager.Configuration);
            })
            .UseNLog();
}
```

start.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
        services.AddDbContext<IDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["add:connString:connectionString"])); 
        services.AddControllers(); 
         
    }
```

In the program.cs, i can see value inserted to my database log successfully so i am sure my configuration for NLog is working. If I use it as Dependency Injection is not inserting the log to database but i can see by the debugger that the ILogger does related to NLog.

Am i missing the some setting? I follow the same step in https://kdrenski.com/wp/using-nlog-and-asp-net-core-3-1-to-log-to-the-database/

Comment: Also fails when using `_logger.LogError("...")` ? Usually Microsoft ILogger filtering is giving issues https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-3%3F (Notice NLog 5.0 disables Microsoft ILogger filter by default).

Comment: Is working now. Is all because the name of the Logger element not match with the name in appsetting.json